# How many different tags are there on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

I would like how many different tags, not counting synonyms, are there on Stack Overflow. Has anyone the capability to find that out?

Comment: You have two ways of getting that information: [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) & [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs)

Comment: @Yannis, I didn't know of SEDE. It is a great tool for site statistics!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name, there are 983 pages of tags. pages 1-982 each list 36 tags, and page 983 has another 20 tags. That is **35,372** tags, including synonyms.

As one user commented on the question, you can see some stats on https://data.stackexchange.com/. This indicates that SO has **33,233** tags. Not sure why the discrepancy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Clever solution.

Comment: The data.SE is not using the most up to date data, so that could be the issue.  It's also possible that it doesn't count tags with 0 questions.